# Навигация по сайту с помощью клавиатуры

Tags: javascript, tab, навигация

Необходимо создать навигацию по сайту, к примеру с помощью клавиши пробел или shift+стрелка выделять первый элемент на странице, а если фокус на каком-либо элементе есть, то выделять следующий. То есть эмулировать tab, только рекурсивно переходить по всем элементам странице, чтобы не было перехода на меню браузера.

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(event) {
if(event.keyCode===32){
    // тут логика
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Логика (без кода) примерно такая:

1) Сохранить в массив все могущие стать активными элементы

2) При нажатии нужной клавиши определять индекс текущего выделенного элемента в массиве

3) Увеличить индекс на 1, выделить следующий элемент из массива.

4) Если не выделен никакой элемент или последний - выделить первый (нулевой).

Comment: примерно так и думал, спасибо за рекомендации